# How to integrate with alexa app

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have a music application. I have built all the custom skill for my music application and it is working fine in amazon echo device. My question is how do i integrate it with alexa app. I can see spotify, pandora, saavn etc in the music section of alexa app and any song playing from this 3rd party application will appear in playqueue and now playing section in alexa app. So how to integrate? Any ideas or link regarding this will help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Read and follow this: [Submitting the Skill for Certification](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/submit-an-alexa-skill-for-certification.html#submitting-the-skill-for-certification)

> When your skill is ready for publication, you can submit it to Amazon for review. The Submit for Certification button becomes available once all required fields are completed.

---

So make sure you meet all [Certification Requirements](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/certification-requirements-for-custom-skills.html).

> When you submit your skill to the Alexa skills store, it must pass a certification process before it can be published live to Amazon customers. Before you submit your new skill for certification, you should perform your own quality assurance testing.

First, [Policy Testing](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/policy-testing-for-an-alexa-skill.html).

> The following list shows specific examples that we look out for when evaluating whether a skill can be made available on Alexa.

Second, [Security Testing](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/security-testing-for-an-alexa-skill.html).

> To protect customer data, the cloud-based service for your skill must meet Amazon’s security requirements.

Third, [Functional Testing](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/functional-testing-for-a-custom-skill.html).

> The functional tests verify that: The skill’s basic functionality matches the information displayed on the skill’s detail card in the Amazon Alexa app. ...[And] the skill’s core functionality works and provides useful home cards to the Amazon Alexa app.

Fourth, [Voice Interface and User Experience Testing](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/voice-interface-and-user-experience-testing-for-a-custom-skill.html).

> Voice interface and user experience testing focuses on: Testing the user experience to ensure that the skill is aligned with several key features of Alexa that help create a great experience for customers. [And] reviewing the intent schema, the set of sample utterances, and the list of values for any custom slot types you have defined to ensure that they are correct, complete, and adhere to voice design best practices.